# Implementing Background Capabilities on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, background

I recently just finished an app that basically has an Observer for a Firebase Database, and when a certain attribute changes, sends a banner type notification.
The application works completely, but when I had the app in the background while using the phone, I realized that it doesn't run any code, or send notifications.

How can I implement both having the Observer listening for any changes from the Database in the background, as well as send a notification?

Here is the **Notification Authorization** Request function:

```
func requestNotificationAuthorization() {
    let authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.init(arrayLiteral: .alert, .badge, .sound)
    
    self.userNotificationCenter.requestAuthorization(options: authOptions) { (success, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error: ", error)
        }}}
```

The **Notification Center** function:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    completionHandler()
}
```

And the **Send Notification** function:

```
func sendNotification() {
    // Create new notifcation content instance
    let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()

    // Add the content to the notification content
    notificationContent.title = "P2P Tracker"
    notificationContent.body = (PriceTimeDate ?? "")
    print(notificationContent.body)
    notificationContent.badge = NSNumber(value: 1)

    // Add an attachment to the notification content
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "dune",
                                    withExtension: "png") {
        if let attachment = try? UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "dune",
                                                            url: url,
                                                            options: nil) {
            notificationContent.attachments = [attachment]
        }
    }
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 3,
                                                    repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "testNotification",
                                        content: notificationContent,
                                        trigger: trigger)
    userNotificationCenter.add(request) { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Notification Error: ", error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Short answer: you can't. You'll instead have to listen for such changes on a server, and use APNS or FCM to send a notification to the user. See for an example: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens

Comment: What about permitted background task schedulers? and thanks I'll look into this